# Need help understanding hashes in `npm audit` output

Tags: npm, npm-audit

in my `npm audit` output I saw the following entry with a hash:

```
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ 050fb87979f5c6895917ef26a696d57ebf3cf1… │
│               │ > mocha > growl                         │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

May I know what the hash stands for and where can I find the dependency tree node it represents? I searched online and searched through my `package-lock.json` file but couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Somehow I was able to figure it out not long after posting it, by using `npm ls growl`. It shows that the hash represents an internal package. (The confusing part is that some internal packages were displayed by package name in `npm audit` output while some were displayed as hashes. | Update: it turns out that we are importing some package by their git commit directly, in those case those dependencies are displayed as hashes.)

Comment: This is related to issue at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20739 - I don't know how `npm audit` calculates that hash as it is not the same as the actual hash of the commit used and it makes it hard to audit code without a lot of manual `npm ls <module-name>` commands

Comment: Is it possible for an MVCE?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. The issue is to obscure the package name for security reasons. After looking into the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit#scrubbing) this has been resolved in Version 7. I just ran npm audit using npm 7+ and it has pointed to the exact packages that are the culprit with no hash.